# win8 cocos2d-x privacy policy

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, cocos2d-x

I have a problem during I publish my windows 8 metro app to the windows store. According to the instructions, I should add privacy policy in my app. But I don't know how to add the privacy policy in the cocos2d-x for windows 8 application. The solution on the Internet are all with normal C# windows 8 application. So I confuse how to solve the cocos2d-x for windows 8 privacy policy problem. Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to publish game without privacy policy.

Comment: Thanks, privacy policy is needed when you want to connect the Internet. I found the solution after all.